# Некорректная работа интерфейса Linux

Tags: linux, debian, интерфейс, gnu

Компьютер предназначен для использования сервера. Долгое время может быть включен без перезагрузок. Давно уже подозревал, что до добра такой не доведет и вот сегодня появилась довольно значительная проблема:
Интерфейс перестал нормально функционировать. Кнопок закрытия, сворачивания и тп на окнах приложений нету. Окна невозможно растянуть на весь экран или переместить. Некоторые кнопки в самих приложениях (например, браузер) попросту не активируются после нажатия. Не работает выделение экрана на ПКМ на рабочем столе.
Даже приблизительно не представляю в чем собственно проблема. Кэш весь почистил уже. И самое интересное, что на других учетных записях (проблемы на root-e) все работает адекватно и исправно.

Comment: В каталоге /root проверь файлы начинающиеся с ".", это файлы конфигурации, некоторые из них относятся к графической оболочке. Попробуй сравнить с аналогичными от других пользователей. Если захочешь удалить и пересоздать - помни, что нужно сохранить права доступа к этим файлам

Comment: @svmitin быть может Вы что то не верно указали в своем совете? в каталоге /root есть только каталоги по типу "Загрузки", "Документы" и тп

Comment: сервер, браузер, DE из под root, проблемы - и почему я не удивлён

Comment: Рекомендую к прочтению любую книжку по Linux для начинающих. В ней расскажут о файлах, которые начинаются с точки. В Unix такие файлы считаются скрытыми и по умолчанию не отображаются. Еще в этой книжке расскажут почему крайне нежелательно запускать графический интерфейс от имени root.

Comment: Чтобы не было непонимания того, почему все молчат расскажу, что Linux настраивается из терминала (командной строки). И ваша проблема решается только общением с терминалом. Если вы не знаете что такое dot-files, вероятно и опыт работы в терминале на нуле, соответственно никто ничем помочь не сможет. Если брать в учет Desktop Environment (DE) запущенный под root, можно предположить что в Linux вы новичок, к тому же с очень размытой проблемой, которую не сможете решить самостоятельно. На StackOverflow за вас проблему никто не решит, только направят в нужную сторону

Comment: Мне тоже интересно зачем тебе на сервере графическое окружение?

Comment: @donRumata Ну во-первых, конечно, из за неопытности работы - я делаю это все на производственной практике. Во-вторых, для проверки работоспособности сервера, как минимум первоначальную настройку программы нужно было делать из браузера.

Comment: @svmitin Вы, конечно, правы насчет моей неопытности и незнания каких-либо основных принципов работы Unix систем. Я учту ваши предложения и обязательно займусь данным изучением позже, но в свое оправдание все же скажу, что я лишь студент и стараюсь изучать материал по мере надобности, в силу того, что не знал, что подобное мне в принципе пригодится. И несмотря на мою "неопытность", я довольно много узнал о Linux пока пытался решать проблемы, которые неоднократно встречал на своем пути в настройке и использовании на Linux.

Comment: Так. Практика, ок. Тогда тебе лучше задавать вопрос не "как победить гуй на сервере", а "как победить <конкретная проблема серверного характера>". Для редактирование конфигов тебе гуй не нужен, поверь. Если прям не терпится - воткни `webmin`.

Comment: Чё кстати за прога, которую нужно настраивать из браузера?

Comment: @donRumata С опозданием, конечно, но все же отвечу -  Zabbix.

Comment: @donRumata Да, я тогда еще не понимал, что такое локальное подключение по IP. Но зато сейчас с этим все нормально, даже по ssh работать начал..! Кстати, если интересно, то я запостил новую задачу.

Comment: Ну так ты поставил чистый безгуёвый линукс и настроил там заббикс?

Comment: @donRumata ну, не без гуевый, конечно, но поставил и настроил. Много времени уже прошло с того момента, да и было это на практике производственной. Сейчас вот продолжаю изучение линукса методом создания веб-сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Век живи - век учись!

Перед началом работы с новым ПО всегда сначала следует изучить суть его работы и понять как делать можно, а как не стоит! Вы, конечно, можете начинать сломя голову пытаться разобраться со всем и сразу, как сделал я, но лучше все же стоит думать прежде чем делать.

Чтобы не возникало подобных проблем всегда используйте при работе обычного пользователя с правами sudo. А еще лучше, если не уверены, что вам нужен веб-интерфейс системы, то используйте ОС без нее (можно довольно легко настроить подключение по ssh, нужно всего лишь загуглить). А проверять работу сервиса можно тем же способом, что написан в вашем гайде, только с другого устройства (с веб интерфейсом. Например: Windows), которое находится в вашей локальной сети.